# pm2: The system cannot find the specified path (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm trying to run pm2 on a x64 windows 8.1 Machine, after a couple of problems I succesfully installed pm2, but now that I'm trying to run it I receive the following error:

The system cannot find the path specified.

The error comes from the pm2.cmd file, which contains the following code:

@IF EXIST "%~dp0/bin/sh.exe" (
"%~dp0/bin/sh.exe" "%~dp0\node_modules\pm2\bin\pm2" %*
) ELSE (
/bin/sh "%~dp0\node_modules\pm2\bin\pm2" %*
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pm2 cant run in windows, because:

> PM2 is a production module, who should be mainly used on Linux
>   servers. It hasnt been tested on other platforms than Linux.

Here is the official issue  at the repo:
https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/6

Comment: Thank you! I guess there's nothing I can do then

Comment: You can run it in virtualbox or similar software. Good part of node.js programs won't run on windows as well, so it might be the best solution in the general case.

Comment: I was able to run pm2 on windows through git bash

Comment: @edua_glz you can use [pm2-windows-startup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2-windows-startup) to run it as a service these days